# Gmail Mailbox updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, gmail-api

I have created a app in Ruby on Rails in that I want to get the all updates of the gmail mailbox, I tried with push notification provided by gmail in this link https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push but in this we get only those message related to that topic, but if i want notification on my server for all the messages then what approach should i adopt,

Please let me know if any one have any idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

The topic is a separate issue from what `labelIds` to get changes for. [The reference for watch()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch#request-body) says that if you don't specify any `labelIds` in the watch, then you will get all the changes to the mailbox.

Comment: The topics which I am creating are they at application level or at user level ? @Tholle

Comment: @TestAccount The topic is on an application level, but you have to call [watch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch#request-body) for every user you want to get notifications for.

Comment: I went through all the steps but the problem is when I am executing the watch methods for the user and I am passing the topic and label also but the problem is its giving error topic name does not exist so when we are publishing the topic we need to give the zone and disc compulsory because I had not done that by passing the zone and disk, so is that the problem @Tholle

Comment: @TestAccount I don't know I'm afraid. I've only implemented push notifications twice myself, and the official guide has worked for me.

Comment: Did you purchase the service account ? @tholle